# Problems installing Ruby on rails with apache2 on ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache2, ubuntu-server

Using the guide found on http://www.modrails.com/install.html I installed Ruby on rails and phusion-passenger for deployment with apache2. (on ubuntu-server) (This is not the development server). The rails script works fine when i run "rails -s", but when I try to access the server using apache I get a "500 - Internal server error".

The error file from apache:

```
[Fri Apr 27 22:52:01 2012] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Fri Apr 27 22:52:02 2012] [warn] module passenger_module is already loaded, skipping
[Fri Apr 27 22:52:02 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.20 (Ubuntu) Phusion_Passenger/2.2.11 PHP/5.3.6-13ubuntu3.6 with Suhosin-Patch configured -- resuming normal operations
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require': no such file to load -- phusion_passenger/utils (LoadError)
[Fri Apr 27 22:52:02 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.20 (Ubuntu) Phusion_Passenger/2.2.11 PHP/5.3.6-13ubuntu3.6 with Suhosin-Patch configured -- resuming normal operations
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require': no such file to load -- phusion_passenger/utils (LoadError)
    from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/phusion_passenger/passenger-spawn-server:53:in `<main>'
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require': no such file to load -- phusion_passenger/utils (LoadError)
    from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/phusion_passenger/passenger-spawn-server:53:in `<main>'
[ pid=1140 file=ext/apache2/Hooks.cpp:727 time=2012-04-27 22:52:08.639 ]:
Unexpected error in mod_passenger: Cannot spawn application '/var/www/steffen/rails': The spawn server has exited unexpectedly.
Backtrace:
    in 'virtual Passenger::Application::SessionPtr Passenger::ApplicationPoolServer::Client::get(const Passenger::PoolOptions&)' (ApplicationPoolServer.h:471)
    in 'int Hooks::handleRequest(request_rec*)' (Hooks.cpp:523)

<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require': no such file to load -- phusion_passenger/utils (LoadError)
    from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/phusion_passenger/passenger-spawn-server:53:in `<main>'
[ pid=1139 file=ext/apache2/Hooks.cpp:727 time=2012-04-27 22:52:10.809 ]:
Unexpected error in mod_passenger: Cannot spawn application '/var/www/steffen/rails': The spawn server has exited unexpectedly.
Backtrace:
   in 'virtual Passenger::Application::SessionPtr Passenger::ApplicationPoolServer::Client::get(const Passenger::PoolOptions&)' (ApplicationPoolServer.h:471)
   in 'int Hooks::handleRequest(request_rec*)' (Hooks.cpp:523)
```

Anyone familiar with this error - and feels like helping me our?

As far as I understood this errorlinge is key to figuring out the issue, but googeling and did not help me much.

```
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require': no such file to load -- phusion_passenger/utils (LoadError)
```

Edit: 
I found out my first error was that I wrote "bun" and not "bin" in the mods-enables file in apache. And thus not pointing it to a correct-ruby directory.

I now get an error generated by passenger. Saying the following:

```
Ruby (Rack) application could not be started
Error message:
    no such file to load -- bundler
```

And then it goes on with a long backtrace, i will post a short snippitt here:

```
Backtrace:
0 lib/rubygems/custom_require> 29:in `require'
1 lib/rubygems/custom_require> 29:in `require'
2 /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.12/lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb 325 in     `prepare_app_process'
3 /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.12/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb 156 in `block in initialize_server'
4 /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.12/lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb 572 in `report_app_init_status'
5 /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.12/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb 154 in `initialize_server'
6 /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.12/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb 204 in `start_synchronously'
```

Comment: Please please add more info about how you fixed this. I'm trying to get it working and getting "no such file to load -- phusion_passenger/utils" as well, and a 500 error. Did you use libapache2-mod-passenger? Or did you use the passenger gem and passenger-install-apache2-module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue, then I fixed it by installing passenger via gems.

Visit the Phusion Passenger (mod_rails) website for complete documentation on Passenger.
You will need GCC installed to setup passenger.

Install Passenger via Gem

```
gem install passenger
```

Run the passenger install script for apache2

```
passenger-install-apache2-module
```

Put the following in /etc/httpd/conf.d/passenger.conf (better to copy direct from the passenger-install-apache2-module output)

```
LoadModule passenger_module /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.3/ext/apache2    /mod_passenger.so
PassengerRoot /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.3
PassengerRuby /usr/bin/ruby
```

Original guide is in http://www.interworx.com/support/faq/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-and-passenger/

Answer (score -1):

Try running this on your production machine:

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

Comment: It gives the message "/usr/bin/ruby1.8 /usr/local/bin/rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets" (why is it using ruby1.8 is a new question - Ive installed 1.9.2) (Extra info: Bundle exec ruby --version gives me "ruby 1.9.2")

I still get the same errors after doing this.

Comment: The error could then be from 1.9 only code being executed by the 1.8 interpreter. Can you try `ruby -v` in the terminal? Also, what if you do `sudo bundle exec ruby --version`? It could be that you installed Ruby on your use with RVM, but Apache is running as a different user.

Comment: Buth gives me the 1.9.2 version. And as you said, apache is running on a different user. But both my user and sudo uses 1.9.2. I also tried logging into the apache user and do "ruby -v", and it does also use 1.9.2

Comment: Okey, So it seems I had a small pebcak there. Updates original post with more info and new error related to same problem.

Comment: Case solved, now I just had to install missing gems. I really feel dumb now.